# How do I get a property from a Linux device tree with a bash shell script?

Tags: vivado, device-tree

There's a lot of information in the device tree that gets used in the kernel (where parsing it is easy), but in my build process I need to fetch properties from my device tree from user-space while running inside a container (`/proc/device-tree` is incorrect).  Specifically, I am looking at extracting the partitions of a QSPI flash node (`/amba/spi@ff0f0000/flash@0`) so that I can generate a Xilinx MCS (memory configuration) image that matches what the device tree has in it. How can I fetch properties from the device tree in this case, presumably with a shell script, so that I can pass the correct information to Vivado?

Here is a bare-bones tree (noting that there are tabs, not spaces indenting this):

```
/ {
    amba {
        spi@ff0f0000 {
            flash@0 {
                partition@0 {
                    label = "boot";
                    reg = < 0x0 0x1000000 >;
                };
                partition@1000000 {
                    label = "kernel";
                    reg = < 0x1000000 0x2E80000 >;
                };
                partition@3e80000 {
                    label = "bootscr";
                    reg = < 0x3e80000 0x10000 >;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

So, how can I get the offsets to each of these partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Try querying the sysfs @ /sys/firwmare/devicetree/base.  you can find information pertaining to each node in the device tree.  May be you can get your information there.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to load that information for a device tree in a container?  I've used that for a running system before, but I don't know a way to "update" it with a different dtb than the container host booted with.

Comment: I dont think there is a direct way to mount sysfs:  May be you try this: https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-mount-sys-inside-the-container-with-rw-access-in-unprivileged-mode/97043

Comment: I can mount the sysfs of the host machine, but that's for the amd64 computer that's running the build.  I would need the /sys/firmware/devicetree/base for the device tree of the aarch64 system that the container is building an image for (that I have a .dtb file for inside the container).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you have a device-tree blob, you first need to convert it into a "well-formatted" device-tree source file<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
dtc -I dtb -O dts -o devicetree.dts devicetree.dtb
```

Now that you have a well-formatted source file, you can define some functions to parse it with sed:

```
# pair down one level of the device tree and call ourselves recursively to get the next level
devicetree_get_node() {
    NODE="$1"
    LEVEL="$2"
    if [ -z "${LEVEL}" ]; then LEVEL=0; fi
    THIS_NODE=$(echo "${NODE}" | sed 's|\([^/]*\)/*\(.*\)|\1|')
    if [ -z "${THIS_NODE}" ]; then THIS_NODE="\\/"; fi
    NEXT_NODE=$(echo "${NODE}" | sed 's|\([^/]*\)/*\(.*\)|\2|')
    START_PATTERN="^"
    for I in $(seq 1 ${LEVEL}); do
        START_PATTERN="${START_PATTERN}\t"
    done
    START_PATTERN="${START_PATTERN}${THIS_NODE} {$"
    STOP_PATTERN="^"
    for I in $(seq 1 ${LEVEL}); do
        STOP_PATTERN="${STOP_PATTERN}\t"
    done
    STOP_PATTERN="${STOP_PATTERN}};"
    if [ -z "${NEXT_NODE}" ]; then
        sed -n "/${START_PATTERN}/, /${STOP_PATTERN}/p" | tail -n+2 | head -n-1
    else
        sed -n "/${START_PATTERN}/, /${STOP_PATTERN}/p" | tail -n+2 | head -n-1 |
            devicetree_get_node "${NEXT_NODE}" "$((LEVEL + 1))" \
        ;
    fi
}

# this isn't perfect, but works for simple single-line properties
devicetree_get_property() {
    NODE="$1"
    PROPERTY="$2"
    SLASHES=$(echo "${NODE}" | sed 's|[^/]*||g')
    LEVEL=$((${#SLASHES} + 1))
    PATTERN="^"
    for I in $(seq 1 ${LEVEL}); do
        PATTERN="${PATTERN}\t"
    done
    PATTERN="${PATTERN}${PROPERTY}"
    devicetree_get_node "${NODE}" | sed -n "s/${PATTERN} = \(< \|\"\)\([^\"]*\)\(\"\| >\);/\2/p"
}

devicetree_get_children() {
    NODE="$1"
    NODE_CONTENTS=$(devicetree_get_node "${NODE}")
    echo "${NODE_CONTENTS}" | sed -n 's/\t*\([^ ]*\) {/\1/p'
}
```

and then call these routines to obtain the necessary information about the partitions:

```
DEVICETREE=devicetree.dts
FLASH_NODE=/amba/spi@ff0f0000/flash@0
PARTITIONS=$(cat "${DEVICETREE}" | devicetree_get_children "${FLASH_NODE}")
for PARTITION in ${PARTITIONS}; do
    PART_LABEL=$(cat "${DEVICETREE}" | devicetree_get_property "${FLASH_NODE}/${PARTITION}" 'label')
    PART_OFFSET=$(cat "${DEVICETREE}" | devicetree_get_property "${FLASH_NODE}/${PARTITION}" 'reg' | sed 's/ .*//')
    echo "${PART_LABEL} is at ${PART_OFFSET}"
done
```

<sup>[1]</sup> Note: it is important for this solution that if you are starting with a device-tree source file that you compile and then de-compile it so that the resulting file is "well-formatted".